# How to persist jobs in Jenkins Mesos framework?

Tags: jenkins, mesos, mesosphere, marathon

i have started Jenkins Scheduler (Framework) as Marathon app. Now if the Jenkins Scheduler dies somehow, the Marathon will  restart it. But all the jobs and settings will be gone. How to persist jobs in Jenkins Mesos framework if it dies and started again?

Answer (score 1):

The Jenkins plugin for Mesos does not yet support scheduler HA. To do so, the scheduler would need to persist the frameworkId remotely somewhere (ZK?) and try to reregister with the same frameworkId when it restarts. We'd also need to set the failover_timeout to a sufficient duration. Bonus points: persist task state and perform task reconciliation on reregistration.

I filed a new github issue for this: https://github.com/jenkinsci/mesos-plugin/issues/147